# My terminal background keep changing after each restart

Tags: macos, mac, terminal, customization

I have this in my `~/.bash_profile`

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/username/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$PATH
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
export PS1="\w $: "
export CLICOLOR=1
export LSCOLORS=gxfxcxdxbxegedabagacad
#export LSCOLORS=exfxcxdxbxegedabagacad
#alias ls='ls -GFh'
```

and for some reason, whenever i restart the `terminal` it changes the color. I want to keep the background of my terminal in RGB 484848 ... but it changes to white and then silver and then bluish after each restart

I don't know what did i do.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that you are using the profile named `Solid Colors` in Terminal.  Each time the terminal opens, it cycles to a random background within `/Library/Desktop\ Pictures/Solid\ Colors/` folder.  If you press Command-i, the inspector will open and you can change the settings of your current window.

Try clicking to "Pro" and then back to "Solid Colors" a few times.  You should get different a effect from Solid Colors nearly every time you come back to it.

I believe that you will have to make a new settings profile with the background color you want and then set that profile as the default.

Comment: how can i make that setting profile

Comment: Thanks!  I always wondered what was meant by "solid colors."  Perhaps they should have called it "random" or something a little less esoteric.